# Align span along with the custom checkbox after check with pseudo element :before

Tags: html, css, checkbox, pseudo-element

I have a custom checkbox it's working nicely but i have some problems having the alignment of the span inside the label in the HTML,

Here is the code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkRemember">
    <input type="checkbox" class="uniform" name="remember" id="chkRememberMe">
    <label for="chkRememberMe">
        <span>Remember Me</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.checkRemember {
    display: inline-block;
}

.checkRemember > input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

.checkRemember > input[type="checkbox"] ~ label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1;
    background: white;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    clear: both;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.checkRemember > input[type="checkbox"] ~ label > span {
    display:block;
    width: 125px;
    padding-left: 18px;
}
.checkRemember > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
    content: '\2714';
    position: relative;
    left: 0.15em;
    top: -1pt;
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: #565656;
    clear: both;
}
```

**Problem**: Checkbox appears correctly but when i check that checkbox the span inside label moves down, Is there anyway to make that normal when we check that checkbox?

### A [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3XyxA/2/) to illustrate problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
.checkRemember > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
    clear: both;
    color: #565656;
    content: "✔";
    float: left;//add this
    font-size: 9pt;
    left: 0.15em;
    position: relative;
    top: 1pt;//change
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3XyxA/5/)

Comment: Thank you +1! I can go with this solution. Looks perfect now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
.checkRemember > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
content: '\2714';
position: absolute;
left: 1em;
top: 8pt;
font-size: 9pt;
color: #565656;
clear: both;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to you code

```
[for=chkRememberMe]{position:relative;}
[for=chkRememberMe] span{position:absolute;}
```

## [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/3XyxA/3/)

The porblem is that when the checkbox is not checked it looks like this:
[image]

and when it is checked it looks like this :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it blinks a bit when we check it! i know we can adjust `top` value but looking for some concrete solution:)

Comment: I'm also checking in chrome 36.